# What is meant by "go on course"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-choice

What is the most suitable word that substitutes for **"go on"** in the following sentence:

> *If too many people want to **go on the morning course**, we will have a second class in the afternoon.*

Is it **enroll** or **attend**?

Answer (score 1):

There are several choices.  You can do any of these -- and notice the prepositions are different:

> - **sign up** *for* a course
> - **enroll** *in* a course
> - **take** a course  -- (*no preposition!*)

In American English, the following is not acceptable, but it might be okay elsewhere:

> - **do** a course

### Add vs. Have

In your example, you might want to say "**add** a second class" instead of "have a second class", to emphasize that you'll be *creating more spaces for students*.

### Course vs. Class

In your example, you use both "course" and "class".  Some people would prefer you to use the same word both times (for **parallelism**), or you can even drop the second one -- see the examples below.

Informally, the words "course" and "class" are interchangeable, so this is totally understandable.  But in American colleges and universities, in official writing, "course" might be used to represent all **instances** or **"sections"** or **"class times"** that the same material is offered.

At my university, they used "sections" to mean different "meeting times" of the same "course".

> Among our **courses**, Economics 101 is the most popular, with **classes** offered at 10 AM, 11 AM, 2 PM and 4 PM.
>
> Among our **courses**, Economics 101 is the most popular, with **sections** meeting four times a day.

So any of these would be good:

> - **✓ Yes:** If too many people want to **take** the morning class, we will add a second class in the afternoon.
> - **✓ Yes:**  If too many people **enroll in** the morning section, we will add a second (section) in the afternoon.
> - **✓ Yes:**  If too many people **enroll in** the morning class, we will add a second (class) in the afternoon.
> - **✓ Yes:**  If too many people **join** the morning class, we will add a second one in the afternoon.

Notice in the examples above, you can drop the second "class", or substitute the word "one" if you like.  It is not necessary to have "class" and then "course" (or vice versa) -- the reader will wonder what the difference is.

### What about "join"?

A commenter suggested "join a course", but this is not the best use of **join**.

The "course" is an abstract concept, a collection of ideas, so I don't think of "joining" it.  The word "join" has a **shade of meaning** that includes **sticking together or adhesion** -- that you join with other people who **also** join with you.

So you can:

> - **✓ Yes:** join a movement
> - **✓ Yes:** join a political party
> - **✓ Yes:** join a group
> - **✓ Yes:** join a class of people
> - **✓ Yes:** join a class of students

But not:

> - *No:* join a course

because the "course" is not the people, it is the collection of concepts and ideas that are being studied.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: You’re welcome!  If this answer is complete, please accept it with the green check mark button.  If you need more please comment. Thanks for contributing and keep learning!

Comment: Yes indeed, your answer if fully complete. Kindly, which "check mark button" you are referring to?

Comment: When you have received an answer that you believe is "complete", use the "checkmark" (right next to the answer, close to the up and down "**voting**" arrows) to mark it as accepted.   You can also **wait** to see if you get additional answers.  Learn [more here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer). Keep contributing!

Comment: OK. Already done!